# How to do normal lazy load in ionic 3 without using preloadModules:true

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, lazy-loading

I am using lazy load in ionic 3 to load the pages on demand, but in app.module.ts if i am adding

```
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, { **preloadModules:true** }),
```

then everything works fine but there is some minor issue with ion-icon.

When i use

```
<ion-icon name="ios-calendar"></ion-icon>
```

it shows icon but when i change icon name to calendar only it doesn’t show anything.

When i use

```
<button ion-button menuToggle>
  <ion-icon name="ios-menu"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

It doesn’t show toggle button in header. When i remove menuToggle attribute from button, It shows toggle button. (i.e. functionality not work)

And second case is when i am using lazy load without preloadModules:true then i am getting error

```
**Error: No component factory found for HomePage . Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents? at noComponentFactoryError (core.js:3929)**
```

Comment: Please share full code from you ngModule and Homepage to show how exactly you did lazy loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two separate issues here:
1. Lazy Loading
2. Icons

This is answer to #2. The right way to add platform specific icons is to use platform specific attribute and not just use name for all of them:

```
  <!--Basic: auto-select the icon based on the platform -->
  <ion-icon name="calendar"></ion-icon>

  <!-- Advanced: explicity set the icon for each platform -->
  <ion-icon ios="ios-calendar" md="md-calendar"></ion-icon>
```

Comment: Ok great. Thanks for the help. And for the answer 1 i am able to use it now, what i was doing was passing the component instead of page name in the navCtrl. But at some places in the html this works directly <!--Basic: auto-select the icon based on the platform -->
  <ion-icon name="calendar"></ion-icon> that is i am not specifying platform specific icons and it works